# Error 1064 in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a row in two tables (users and account) with a transaction.

### This is the code i'm using:

```
include 'DB.php';

$last_id= mysqli_insert_id($connessione);
$id = $last_id +1;
echo "$id";
echo "<br>";

$sql="start transaction;
insert into account (user_id, username, activation_date, passw) values 
('$id','$username',CURDATE(),'$password');

insert into users (user_id,name,surname,birth,email) values ('$id','$name', 
'$surname','$birth','$mail');
commit work;";
```

---

in db.php i have the connection to the database. 
It gives me this error:

---

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into account (user_id, username, activation_date, passw) values...

---

What could it be?

Comment: `mysqli` has its own methods to start/end transaction. Also, unless you use `multi_query`, `mysqli` will not execute several queries in one call.

Comment: Beside what u_mulder wrote, `$id = $last_id +1;` looks like a terrible idea.